# Cannot catch Zend Framework exception

Tags: exception, zend-framework2, try-catch

I've got a Zend Framework application based on the basic skeleton. So there's a `public/index.php` file, and in there, the application is started:

```
Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require 'config/application.config.php')->run();
```

My problem is that somewhere in there a PDOException is thrown and I cannot catch it. I've tried wrapping the `run` statement in try/catch block but without success:

```
try {
    Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require 'config/application.config.php')->run();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    die("Caught!");
}catch (\PDOException $e) {
    die("Caught!");
}
```

But this doesn't catch the exception, it's still showing the generic "An error occurred" page. In fact, I've tried throwing generic exceptions too and likewise they cannot be caught. I've also tried setting up a `set_exception_handler` function but still no luck.

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found what the issue was. ZF2 has its own non-standard way to deal with exceptions. In ZF, exceptions are not just mere exceptions, they are "MvcEvents", and they are not caught with vulgar try/catch blocks but need to be "attached" to, via the application object, via an "event manager", via an "attach" method, via a "EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR" constant (they could call it "EXCEPTION" I guess, but that would be too easy).

So the solution is:

```php
function zendFrameworkErrorHandler(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $event) {
    echo "Got exception: " . (string)$event->getParam('exception');
}

$application = Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require 'config/application.config.php');
$application->getEventManager()->attach(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, 'zendFrameworkErrorHandler');
$application->run();
```